# не работает gulp pug

Tags: gulp, pug

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет!
Не работает gulp pug. Сам подключен как npm i gulp-pug --save-dev

В gulpfile.js имеется:

```
const pug = require('gulp-pug');

gulp.task('pug', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/pug/*.pug')
      .pipe(pug())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('src/temphtml/'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Хочу получить html, а выдает такую картину. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: пожалуйста, скопируйте вывод из консоли на вашем снимке экрана и разместите его в тексте вашего вопроса

Answer (score 0):

У меня так работает.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug');

gulp.task('pug', function buildHTML() {
  return gulp.src('src/pug/*.pug')

    .pipe(pug({
      pretty: true
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Разобрался.
У себя в pug файле косяк нашел(